# Query doesn't work android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing a simple Android application with SQL. I followed the following guides - [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

I get an error when trying to do a query the database.

Here is my DataBaseHelp.Java Class :

```
package namae.nombebe;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/namae.nombebe/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "myDBName";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
       // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
       // to you to create adapters for your views.
}
```

What i trying to do :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(null);
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try 
    {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try 
    {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle)
    {
        throw sqle;
    }

    myDataBase = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM A", null);
```

// problem on this query
    }

So i don't have any idea what going wrong.

I try with a simply database name "test.sqlite3", there are two table "android_metadata" and "A".

I have done 
    INSERT INTO "android_metadata" VALUES ('en_US')

And in A there only 2 column _id and TEXT, there is only one value "hello!" and "10".

The error i have is :

> 07-30 13:39:03.886: E/AndroidRuntime(307): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{namae.nombebe/namae.nombebe.NomBebeActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: A: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM A

So if anyone have any idea thanks in advance.
I have looking for hours.

Comment: what  is error, explain?

Comment: @jeet error help you ? Or someone else have any idea ?

Comment: That error has nothing to do with your database and something to do with some widget you've apparently created.  `Error inflating class com.att.widgets.lib.button.SegmentedTextToggleButton`

Comment: Argh sorry it's was the wrong error i'm a little bit tired right now.
So like you can see it doesn't find my Table "A" and  i really don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate, your code creates an empty DB, and then you are checking it from your activity and it already exists and the copy code doesn't run. Thus the message that your table doesn't exist when you then try to query.

An example DBAdapter class:

```
public class DBAdapter {

    // tool groups table
    public static final String TOOL_GROUP_TABLE = "ToolGroups";
    public static final String TOOLGROUP_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String TOOLGROUP_DESCRIPTION = "GroupDescription";

    // DB info
    public static final String MAIN_DATABASE_NAME = "yourDB";
    public static String MAIN_DB_PATH = "/data/data/your.package.name/databases/";
    public static final int MAIN_DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // database control
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private static SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context, String dbname, int dbversion) {
            super(context, dbname, null, dbversion);
            if (checkDataBase(dbname)) {
                openDataBase(dbname);
            } else {
                try {
                    this.getReadableDatabase();
                    copyDataBase(dbname);
                    this.close();
                    openDataBase(dbname);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Initial " + dbname + " database has been created",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        DBAdapter.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public DBAdapter open(String dbname, int dbversion) throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx, dbname, dbversion);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    private static void copyDataBase(String dbname) throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = mCtx.getAssets().open(dbname);
        String outFileName = MAIN_DB_PATH + dbname;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    private static boolean checkDataBase(String dbname) {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        boolean exist = false;
        try {
            String db = MAIN_DB_PATH + dbname;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.v("db log", "database does't exist");
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            exist = true;
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return exist;
    }

    private static void openDataBase(String dbname) throws SQLException {
        String dbPath = MAIN_DB_PATH + dbname;
        mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllGroups() {
        return mDb.query(TOOL_GROUP_TABLE, new String[] { TOOLGROUP_ROWID,
            TOOLGROUP_DESCRIPTION }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

Then you call it from your activity like this:

```
myDBHelper = new DBAdapter(this);  // constructor copies database if it doesn't exist yet
myDBHelper.open(DBAdapter.MAIN_DATABASE_NAME, DBAdapter.MAIN_DATABASE_VERSION);
Cursor toolGroupCursor = mDBHelper.fetchAllGroups();
```

Comment: are you sure there is an argument in checkDataBase ? Because eclipse offers me to remove argument because that doesn't work.

Comment: It depends on how you created the method (Sorry for the confusion, I pasted code from one of my projects).  I created it so I could feed it a DB name as I have used this code to copy multiple databases in one app.  I'll add one of those methods to my answer just so you can see what I did.  If you only have one DB, you can hardcode the name/path in the method(s) and not feed it the db name.

Comment: Ah ok so i need "openDataBase" and "copyDataBase". But this methods are in the class DatabaseHelper ?

Comment: I need "MAIN_DB_PATH" too. can you give the class with everything ?

Comment: If you followed that tutorial, they are methods you should have created in a `DBAdapter` class (which also contains the `DatabaseHelper` class).  I've updated my answer to show a general layout for a dbadapter class.  I usually put everything related to the Db in my DBAdapter class, constant strings, everything.

Comment: I'm a little bit confuse. In the tutorial there is nothing about DBAdapter class. Can you give me all of your class for see what's going wrong with what i've done ?

Comment: i still not understand what you have done. "mDBHelper" should be "DBAdapter" type ? Because how i do after to do query on mDBHelper ? myDataBase = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase(); i would like to do that but method isn't in DBAdapter class. I trying for 2 days but still not working :(

Comment: You write methods in the DBAdapter that do the query and return the cursor generated to your activity.  For example, you create a method called `fetchAll` in the adapter that queries the db for all the records in a table and returns the cursor generated by the query.  Then in your activity, after you have instantiated the adapter and opened the db, you would use it with a line like this:  `Cursor allCursor = mDBHelper.fetchAll();`

Comment: I need to use get writableDatabase() but in DBAdapter i just have to do a methods who call the method of "SQLiteOpenHelper" ?

Comment: public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
  return this.getWritableDatabase();
 }
I've done that but it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't overwrite anything else, you simply create methods that return a cursor... I added a small table and an example query of said table and how to call it from your activity to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is not referred to your sqlite usage. You have some issue with your activity

Comment: Argh sorry it's was the wrong error i'm a little bit tired right now. So like you can see it doesn't find my Table "A" and i really don't know why.